# Content фиксированый по высоте в зависимости о размера броузера

Tags: css3, jquery-ui, javascript, html5

Вот такой код;

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Документ без названия</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mu.css">
    </head>

<style>
body{
    margin:0;
}

#wraper {
min-width:1024px;
width:100%;
outline:1px solid #0F0;
}
#heder {
height: 126px;
width: 100%;
margin-bottom:6px;
outline:1px solid #000;
}
#content{
width:100%;
overflow: auto;
outline:1px solid #F00;
}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 1600px) {
   content {height: 1500px;}
   }
   @media screen and (device-width: 1280px) {
    content {height: 1100px;}
   }
   @media screen and (device-width: 1024px) {
    content {height: 980px;}
   }

#contener {
background-image: url(../images/tiny_grid.png);
background-repeat:repeat;
border:1px solid #FF0;
min-height:5000px;
min-width: 850px;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="wraper">
    <div id="heder">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contener"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Задача сделать блок content фиксированым по высоте в зависимости о размера броузера(всегда принемал высоту браузера). Чтобы не у браузера прокрутка поевлялась, а у блока content. Получаться как width:100%;, но нодо для height.

Можноли это сделать спомощью медиазапросов или javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('#content').height($(window).height());
})
```